# Help with identifying LEGO sets

Tags: city, friends, set-identification

Our family (with very big hearts) gave us some LEGO they found.
But... I do not know what sets they are from. I already identified 11 sets, but cannot find the last 4 (I think)

Could you please help?

1. Construction machines

[image]

2. Recycling truck

[image]

3. Girl car

[image]

4. Firetrucks

[image]

Please, do not pay attention to the state they are in. I still need to clean them. But I'm reluctant to dismantle them until I know what set they are on ( and have a manual to put them back together) .. yep, I'm a freak ;-)

Please, any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that this covers everything:

Construction vehicles:

- [Diesel Dumper (6532)](http://brickset.com/sets/6532-1/Diesel-Dumper)
- [Backhoe (6662)](http://brickset.com/sets/6662-1/Backhoe)
- [Landscape Loader (6512)](http://brickset.com/sets/6512-1/Landscape-Loader)

[Recycle Truck (6668)](http://brickset.com/sets/6668-1/Recycle-Truck)

[Friends car (30103)](http://brickset.com/sets/30103-1/Car)

Fire vehicles:

- [Jetport-Fire-Squad (6440)](http://brickset.com/sets/6440-1/Jetport-Fire-Squad)
- [Launch Evac 1 (6614)](http://brickset.com/sets/6614-1/Launch-Evac-1)
- [Rescue Runabout (6511)](http://brickset.com/sets/6511-1/Rescue-Runabout)
- Looks like just the car from [Shell Convenience Store (1254)](http://brickset.com/sets/1254-1/Shell-Convenience-Store)

Comment: The one on the left is [6511-1: Rescue Runabout](http://brickset.com/sets/6511-1/Rescue-Runabout)